# zip files not showing in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I created a new text and zip file in a directory. The text file is showing up in SourceTree "Unstaged files" but not the zip file. When I change the extension of the zip file to something else, it shows up. But no way the ".zip" is show up.
I have checked the gitignore_global.txt file and the extension of ".zip" is not mentioned there.
Why is files with .zip extension not showing ?
My SourceTree version is 3.0.17 and will not be able to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the zip files are not being ignored by your repository's `.gitignore` file. If they are, you'll need to remove them from the `.gitignore` file to see them in SourceTree.

[image: example]
*Note: The **.gitignore** file is a hidden file located in the project directory.*

Comment: thanks for the info. Yes that was causing the issue